# A python function which removes reacquiring numbers from the parameters

Tags: python-3.x

[image]

im trying to return a function that removes numbers which appear in a list more than once. Could anyone provide guidance on where im going wrong?

Comment: Please post your code as text, not in an image.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append `x`, which is never defined anywhere.